# Understanding practical usage of __ (double underscore) in python

Tags: python, variables

I saw functions returning tuples and at receiving end, sometimes I see syntax something like this.

```
def foo():
    return (True, False)

foo, __ = foo()
```

The thing I investigated is that, `__` (double underscore) don't give `pep8` error as if its not being used anywhere.

### Seeking:

1. the practice situation where we should use this
2. Situations we should avoid
3. Any alternatives.

Comment: Do you mean to use a single underscore?

Comment: Not single, a double underscore.

Comment: **Double underscores** are commonly used for **`magic methods`**. A **single underscore** is a convenient way to discard unpacked values in certain position(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Andrés Pérez-Albela H. has mentioned, double underscores are usually used for "magic methods" like `__init__()`. In that usage, they lead *and* trail the method name. A single underscore in front of a method (or variable) name, like `_index`, usually means "this is a private member variable or a private method, and should not be used by other code". This is simply convention and does not have any special meaning to the Python interpreter, whereas some double-underscore methods *do* have special meaning.

Now, as for the question you asked: `__` (a double underscore) as a variable name is not a normal thing in Python coding. The more usual convention is to use `_` (a single underscore) for any variable whose contents you don't need. See [What is the purpose of the single underscore "_" variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5893163/2314532) for more details.

However, there are sometimes reasons why a programmer might want to avoid using `_` as a variable name. Specifically, if he's running code in an interactive Python interpreter session. In an interactive session, the value returned from the previous expression is stored in a variable named `_`. So if you're used to using `_` as "a variable whose contents I don't care about" but you're in an interactive Python interpreter session, you might switch to using `__` for that purpose instead.

So my best guess is that the sample code you've seen was intended to be run in an interactive Python session, where `_` already has a special meaning. And so the person writing the code used `__` for his throwaway variables, instead of `_` which would be more commonly used.

Comment: When you say "the Python interpreter", I think you should instead be specifying an *interactive* interpreter session. Even when you run a script, the "interpreter" is still being used, you just don't interact with it directly as a user.

Comment: @Blckknght - Good point. I've updated my answer to be clearer. Thanks!

Comment: Well explained, Thanks. I got what you mean. +1